# How to give padding/margin to items inside the ExtJS panel

Tags: extjs, panel, padding, margins

I am using `ExtJS 2.3.0`

I have a panel and some items inside that

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    border: false,
    margin: '10px;' // Not working for me
    items: [
            { boxLabel: 'One', xtype: 'checkbox' },
            { boxLabel: 'Two', xtype: 'checkbox' }
    ]
}
```

I tried using margin, padding... none of them is working for me..

Any solutions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [bodyStyle](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-bodyStyle) configuration property:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    border: false,
    bodyStyle: 'margin: 10px;'
    items: [
        { boxLabel: 'One', xtype: 'checkbox' },
        { boxLabel: 'Two', xtype: 'checkbox' }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In **ExtJs 2.3**, there is no support for config options **"margin, padding"** in ***Ext.Panel***.

Check in the documentation http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel

you should go for **bodyStyle** config option.

```js
{
     xtype: 'panel',
     border: false,
     bodyStyle: 'margin: 10px; padding: 5px 3px;',
     items: [
          { boxLabel: 'One', xtype: 'checkbox' },
          { boxLabel: 'Two', xtype: 'checkbox' }
     ]
}
```

Hope this helped you.....

Answer (score 1):

Below should also work:

```
var myForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel ({
title: 'My Form',
width: 400,
height: 250,
padding: '50 10 10 10',
```